# How to call a async task from main()

Tags: c#

I am trying to call this method but it returns **Await operator can only be used within an Async method**

this is the  code.

### code:

```
  static void Main(string[] args)
    {
         config = new InstagramConfig(CliendID, ClientSecret,redirectURI);

          Auth = new OAuth(config);
          var scopes = new List<OAuth.Scope>();
          scopes.Add(OAuth.Scope.Likes);
          scopes.Add(OAuth.Scope.Basic);
          scopes.Add(OAuth.Scope.Comments);
          scopes.Add(OAuth.Scope.Relationships);

          var link = OAuth.AuthLink(config, scopes, OAuth.ResponseType.Code);

          HttpWebRequest myReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(link);
          WebResponse webresponse =  myReq.GetResponse();
          await call();


    }

    public static async Task call()
    {
        var authInfo = new OAuth(config);
        var response = await authInfo.RequestToken("");
        var user = new Users(config, response);
        var media = await user.RecentSelf();
    }
```

How will i rectify this error?

Comment: Add the `async` modifier to Main?

Comment: Awaiting `call` doesn't really accomplish anything in this case.

Comment: @E.Moffat The `Main` method can't be `async`.

Comment: There are many questions on SO already that involve using async methods in the `Main()` method. The marked duplicate is one that appears to be particularly thoroughly addressed, but you should feel free to do your own search. If you still cannot find an answer to your _specific_ need, please post a new question explaining that need in detail, along with describing the SO questions you've already reviewed and why those questions don't address your question.

Comment: Venkat, I'm not sure why would you try to write such code. Assuming you've searched for something like title of your post https://www.bing.com/search?q=How+to+call+a+async+task+from+main() and looked through top answers... I could be wrong and you did not search at all - unlikely as it would warrant downvotes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest thing to do is to block the call and wait.  You're not getting async behavior, but hey - you're in a console app on a single thread anyway.

```
call().Wait();
```

If instead you want true async behavior, including a message pump and synchronization context, (perhaps because you have other things going on in your console app simultaneously), you have a few different options:

1. Use the `AsyncPump` class from [Stephen Toub's MSDN post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/01/20/10259049.aspx).
2. Use the `AsyncContext` class from [Stephen Cleary's AsyncEx project](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx/wiki/AsyncContext).
3. If you're using the new [.NET Core](http://dotnet.github.io/core/) (aka "DNX"), then you can just make your `Main` method async, as in:

   ```
   static async Task Main(string[] args)
   ```